# Concatenate/merge/join/add-content not working properly

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have a text file having some content like session IDs mentioned below, this can be n numbers.

```
session1
Session2
Session3
.
.
Session n
```

By using above session IDs I need to generate and fire command and extract the output in another file.

```
    omnidb -session session1 -detail | findstr "Object"
    omnidb -session session2 -detail | findstr "Object"
    omnidb -session sessionn -detail | findstr "Object"
```

Please help me to write script in PowerShell using text file contenet it generate and fire the command.
**update**
I tried with lots of parameter like Join & Concatenate but i did not get desired output. below script i used but won't work.

```
    $line1= get-content C:\line1.txt $line2= get-content C:\line2.txt 
    $linesession= get-content C:\sesopt0.txt 
    $( $line1," ",$linesession," ",$line2) | Set-Content C:\sesopt1.txt
```

By using this parameter, i am getting output like.

```
omnidb -session 
session1 
session2 
session3 
. 
session n 
-detail | findstr "Object"
```

Which is not as expected. it should use file to fire single line command and generate the output. Please provide your expert view. thanks in advance 
**update**
Just now i tried with below script, its generating the output in console but not sending to file, so that i can use that file to run commands and generate the output.

```
foreach ($server in (Get-Content C:\sesopt1.txt)) 
{ write-host "omnidb -session $server -detail | findstr 'Object'" > C:\sesopt2.txt }
```

Please help thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? What doesn't work as expected? How *exactly* does it not work as expected? Are you getting errors? What do they say?

Comment: I tried with lots of parameter like Join & Concatenate but i did not get desired output. below script i used but won't work.

$line1= get-content C:\line1.txt
$line2= get-content C:\line2.txt
$linesession= get-content C:\sesopt0.txt
$( $line1," ",$linesession," ",$line2) | Set-Content C:\sesopt1.txt

By using this parameter, i am getting output like.
omnidb -session
session1
session2
session3
.
;
session n
-detail | findstr "Object"
Which is not expected. it should use file to fire single line command and generate the output. Please provide your expert view. thanks in advance

Comment: Please [edit] your question. Code in comments is unreadable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bingo !!

i tried self and found the result. thanks everyone.

```
$seopt2= Get-Content C:\sesopt1.txt
$line2= Get-Content C:\line2.txt
$result=foreach ($server in $seopt2) 
{ Write-Output "omnidb -session $server $line2" } 
$result | Set-Content C:\sesopt2.bat
```